# DDD & Factories - Intensive CRUD Operations

Tags: domain-driven-design, factories

We have recently decided to adopt DDD in my team for our new projects because of the so many obvious benefits (coming from the Active-Record pattern school) and there are a couple of things that are yet unclear.

Say I have an entity Transaction that depends on the following entities (that each in turn depends on other so many entities):
1. Customer
2. Account
3. Currency

When I make use of factories to instantiate a Transaction entity to pass to a Domain Service for some fancy business rules, do I make so many queries to setup all these dependent instances?

If I have overloads in my factory that skip such dependencies then those will be null in some cases and it will become too complicated to differentiate when I can access those properties and when I cannot. With Active-Record pattern I just use lazy loading and have them load only on demand. Any ideas with DDD?

EDIT:

In my scenario “Transaction” seems to be the best candidate for an Aggregate root. I have defined a method in my Application Service “InitiateTransaction” (also have a “FinalizeTransaction” as it involves a redirect to PayPal) and takes as parameters the DTOs needed to carry AccountId, CurrencyId, LanguageId and various other foreign keys as well as Transaction attributes.

When calling my Domain Services (Transaction Processor and Fraud Rule Evaluator), I need to specify the “Transaction” Aggregate with all dependencies loaded (“Transaction.Customer”, “Transaction.Currency”, etc.).

So if I am correct the steps required are:
1.  Call some repository(ies) to retrieve Customer, Currency etc.
2.  Call TransactionFactory with dependencies specified above to get a Transaction object
3.  Call Domain Services with fully loaded Transaction object for business rules to take place

Correct? Additionally, my concern was about steps 1 and 2.

If “Customer”, “Currency” and other Entities/Value Objects “Transaction” depends on, have in turn other dependencies. Do I try to set up those as well? Because it seems to me that if I do I will end up with very bloated code in my Application Service and not very reusable to place in a separate method. However, if I don’t and just retrieve those from a repository with a “GetById(id)”as you suggested, my code could end up buggy as say I need property “Transaction.Customer.CreatedByUser” which returns a “User” instance, it will be null because repositories only load flat instances.

EDIT:

I ended up using GetById(id) to load only the dependencies I knew they were needed in my Services. Not a big fun of accidentally accessing null instances due to flat loading but I have my unit tests to protect me from taking it to production!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt it that *Currency* is an entity, however it's important to model things like how they defined and use by the real Domain. Forget factories or other implementation details like the db, you need to make sure you have defined the concepts right.

Once you've done that, you'd already identified the *aggregate root* as well. Btw, the entities should encapsulate the relevant business rules. Use Services to implement use-cases i.e to manage the interaction between the domain objects and other parts such as the repository.

You should keep EVERYTHING related to db and CRUD in the repository, and have the repo work only with the aggregate roots. Also, for querying purposes, you should use CQRS so that all the queries would be done on a read model. For Domain purposes, a Get(id) is 99% enough and that method returns an aggregate root.

Be aware that DDD is very tricky, the most difficult part is modeling the Domain correctly, all the buzzwords are useless if the model is wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I have edited my question to clarify my question as I am still a bit unclear on what is the best approach.

Comment: There's no best approach, it depends on the domain, business,  technological and financial constraints. I can only tell you how I'd do things, it might not be the best approach for you or your company. Don't waste your time searching for recipes (best approaches/design patterns) just do it and learn from mistakes.